# Is it possible to pull a row to the top of a query result in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

For example

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE (id = 2) OR (id = 14) OR (id = 22)
```

And I always want 14 to be the top row. Is this this possible in one query?  I know I could just do two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   foo
WHERE  id IN ( 2, 14, 22 )
ORDER  BY id != 14
```

Answer (score 3):

Other folks have told you how to solve the problem given the conditions specified, but you should ask yourself why you have this requirement in the first place.

If you need the items to display in a certain order and you want it to be driven by the database, you could add a display_order column and ORDER BY it. This leaves you open to changing it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 1 as ordering, * FROM foo WHERE (id = 14)
UNION 
SELECT 2 as ordering, * FROM foo WHERE (id = 2) OR (id = 22) 
ORDER BY ordering ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a column with your order priorities (ordering) and use `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE (id = 2) OR (id = 14) OR (id = 22) ORDER BY ordering
```